# Re render a children of Context Provider react

Tags: reactjs

I have a function App in App.js as below

```
function App() {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <Layout>
                <Routes>
                    {/* Basic routes access allowed by all */}
                    <Route exact path={RoutesNames.GLOBAL} element={<MainHomePage />} />
                    <Route exact path={RoutesNames.LOGIN} element={<Login />} />
                    <Route exact path={RoutesNames.REGISTER} element={<Register />} />
                    <Route exact path={RoutesNames.CATALOGUE} element={<Catalogue />} />

                    {/* Protected routes access allowed by user connected */}
                    <Route exact path={RoutesNames.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS} element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
                        <Route exact path={RoutesNames.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS} element={<RegistrationSuccess />} />
                    </Route>

                    {/* Errors routes */}
                    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
                </Routes>
            </Layout>
        </AuthProvider>
    )
}
```

The **Layout** contain the Header bar and the childrens after.

Now when I login from the login page, I'm redirected to Catalogue Page. And I have my **AuthProvider** who set the isAuth state to true as below :

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react'
import VerificationUserAuth from '../../utils/VerificationUserAuth'

const AuthContext = createContext()

class AuthProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            isAuth: false,
        }
    }

    checkAuth = () => {
        const user = new VerificationUserAuth().getUserConnected()

        if (user) {
            this.setState({ isAuth: true })
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isAuth) {
            this.checkAuth()
        }

        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuth: this.state.isAuth }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer

export { AuthProvider, AuthConsumer }
```

Now the problem is I check in my header who is envelopped by my AuthConsumer if he's authenticated or not and change the menu consequently. But each time I login, i need to refresh the page for Render the AuthProvider who check the authentification.

Btw there is my Header Bar :

```
export default function HeaderBar() {
    return (
        <AuthConsumer>
            {({ isAuth }) => (
                <header className="mb-5">
                            {isAuth ? (
                                <p>Connected</p>
                            ) : (
                                <Navbar.Brand>
                                    <Link to={RoutesNames.LOGIN}>
                                        <Button className="btn btn-rounded btn-primary mr-2">Connexion</Button>
                                    </Link>
                                    <Link to={RoutesNames.REGISTER}>
                                        <Button className="btn btn-rounded btn-normal">S'inscrire</Button>
                                    </Link>
                                </Navbar.Brand>
                            )}
                        </Container>
                    </Navbar>
                </header>
            )}
        </AuthConsumer>
    )
}
```

So how can I re render my header after login part ? Thank's !

Comment: Depends on how HeaderBar is being used

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the isAuth state in a lifecycle component so that means whenever your app is loaded it will be initiated .

Put this function in a lifecycle method :

```
   checkAuth = () => {
        const user = new VerificationUserAuth().getUserConnected()

        if (user) {
            this.setState({ isAuth: true })
        }
    }

  componentDidMount(){
    checkAuth()
  }
```

In a functional component :

```
  checkAuth = () => {
        const user = new VerificationUserAuth().getUserConnected()

        if (user) {
            this.setState({ isAuth: true })
        }
   }

   React.useEffect(()=>{
      checkAuth()
    } , [])
```

Comment: I try that but still not working, I did a console.log('didmount') in the componentDidMount() method and the console.log() doesn't appear when I login and logout. The problem is my AuthProvider didn't re render when I do something

Comment: @MehdiBekbachy If you need to re-render the auth provider you need to change the isAuth state from a route component then it will re-render .